# Adding and Removing UIView From Springboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwindow

I am developing a little MS tweak that adds a view on the Springboard. I want it to be constantly updated so I called it into the

```
- (void)showSpringBoardStatusBar
```

Then I create and add the view using this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:view1];
```

Is this the right way?

But the problem is this view uses a low alpha level to be transparent and every time the view is updated by the showSpringBoardstatus bar another UIView is added onto of it eventually just making the view solid. This also is uneconomical in terms of memory. so then I went back an added what I thought would remove the code:

```
 view1 = nil;
[view1 removeFromSuperview];
```

But it seems like this doesn't make a difference as it is still there and nothing changes.
I have been searching for the last few days for anything to help me with this but got nothing out of it. All I can think of is that I can't remove an added subview from a key window like I would from a normal view or I just don't how to do it correctly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I can't speak to the whole question, but you should call `[view1 removeFromSuperview];` before you call `view1 = nil;`. If you nil out the view1 variable first the way it's written, then the removeFromSuperview method won't do anything.

Answer (score -1):

Setting view1 to nil and than calling "removeFromSuperView" might be a bad idea. How about adding the view only once, keeping a reference and updating this reference constantly without adding it to keyWindow again?